# Selfadjoint Operators: Characterization

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Given a Hilbert space.

Symmetric operators can be described by
$$\overline{\mathcal{D}(A)}=\mathcal{H}:\quad A\subseteq A^*\iff\langle A\varphi,\psi\rangle=\langle\varphi,A\psi\rangle\quad(\varphi,\psi\in\mathcal{D}(A))$$

So that essentially selfadjoint operators can be characterized by:
$$A\subseteq A^*:\quad\overline{A}=A^*\iff A^*\subseteq A^{**}$$
*(The existence of adjoints being implicitely required.)*

Does it fail if symmetry assumption on the original operator is dropped?

> More short, can it happen: $A^*\subsetneq A^{**}=\overline{A}$

Comment: Let $A$ be any closed densely-defined linear operator with $A \prec A^{\star}$ ($\prec$ denotes strict graph inclusion.) Then $B=A^{\star}$ satisfies $B^{\star} \prec B^{\star\star}=B=\overline{B}$.

Comment: @T.A.E.: Ah right so any not (essentially) selfadjoint operator would serve as an example.

Comment: @T.A.E.: Wanna give your comment as short answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B : \mathcal{D}(B)\subset X \rightarrow X$ be any closed densely-defined linear operator on a Hilbert space $X$, with $B \prec B^{\star}$ (I am using $\prec$ to denote strict graph inclusion.) Then $A=B^{\star}$ satisfies $A^{\star} \prec A^{\star\star}$. Indeed, because $B$ is closed and densely-defined, then $B^{\star\star}=\overline{B}=B$, which gives the strict graph inclusion
$$
      A^{\star} =(B^{\star})^{\star}=B \prec B^{\star}= A=\overline{A}=A^{\star\star},
$$
and is as you stated:
$$
               A^{\star} \prec A^{\star\star} = \overline{A}.
$$
**An example** is $X=L^{2}[0,\infty)$ and $B=-i\frac{d}{dx}$ defined on the domain $\mathcal{D}(B)$ consisting of all absolutely continuous functions $f \in X$ for which $f' \in X$ and $f(0)=0$. Then,
$$
                      (Bf,g) = (f,Bg),\;\;\; f,g\in \mathcal{D}(B).
$$
The operator $B$ is closed and densely-defined with adjoint $B^{\star}=-i\frac{d}{dx}$ on the domain $\mathcal{D}(B^{\star})$ consisting of all absolutely continuous $f \in X$ for which $f' \in X$ (without any endpoint condition at $0$.) The opertor $B$ is symmetric, but $A=B^{\star}$ is not.

Answer (score 0):

Any essentially selfadjoint operator is symmetric. So, if you consider as definition for essential selfadjointness $\bar{A}=A^*$ then, automatically, $A\subseteq A^*$ ($A$ is symmetric) since $A$ is contained in its closure $\bar{A}$.

The converse is not true. Some counter-examples and theoretical results can be found here: http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/fun/adjointness_crit.pdf.

Comment: Yes but the converse might fail.

Comment: Of course, there are examples of symmetric operators that are not essentially selfadjoint.

Comment: Yes but the symmetry is on the adjoint: $\overline{A}=A^*\iff A^*\subseteq A^{**}$

Comment: Does it also address the case: $A^*\subsetneq\overline{A}$

Comment: Yes, if you use $A^*\subseteq\bar{A}$ as a definition then you must also add that $A$ is symmetric. This is because, when you pass to adjoints in $A\subseteq A^*$ you will get the converse inclusion $\bar{A}\subseteq A^*$.

Comment: Yep in general the inclusion reverses but it might be redundant as when necessarily equality follows: $A^*\subseteq A^{**}\implies A^*=A^{**}$

Comment: Besides, I just figured out that addressing the closure instead of the double adjoint might be no good idea as the adjoint may have trivial domain: $\mathcal{D}(A^*)=(0)$

Comment: Well, the closure exists for a densely defined operator (i.e., the operator is closable) if and only if its adjoint is densely defined.

Comment: Ah right so it is the same to write $A^*\subseteq\overline{A}$ as writing $A^*\subseteq A^{**}$ as in both case the existence of the adjoint $A^*$ is equivalent to $\overline{\mathcal{D}(A)}=\mathcal{H}$ and then the equivalence on closable operators and double adjoints applies: $\mathcal{G}(\overline{A})=\overline{\mathcal{G}(A)}=\mathcal{G}(A^{**})$

Comment: Ok but then the question is still open: $A^*\subsetneq A^{**}=\overline{A}$

Comment: As I told you before it is possible to find $A$ (it must be non-symmetric) such that $A^*$ is symmetric and not selfadjoint. I do not have an example in hand, but in the next days I will try to find it for you.

Comment: Ah ok cool let me know if you have one.